# Python features

Tags: python, language-features, language-comparisons

Is there any article/paper on what features the Python language has to offer? Why should one go with Python instead of any other language? What are the strong and the weak points of Python?

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageComparisons

Comment: why I like Python: http://www.youtube.com/user/montypython?blend=1&ob=4#p/a/CDFEA6D52E5CC0EC/0/kQFKtI6gn9Y

Comment: Python vs Ruby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673964/should-i-learn-ruby-or-python Python vs Perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150043/python-v-perl These two are probably the languages Python is most often compared to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Why Python](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3882)
and
[Why Python](http://folk.uio.no/hpl/WhyPython.pdf)
so
[Choose Python](http://www1.american.edu/cas/econ/faculty/isaac/choose_python.pdf) ([import this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

Answer (score 3):

Probably the prime reason I use Python is because it's very good at self-documenting. There are lots of other reasons too, but probably the best way to find out is to do something with it. Find a project and see what it takes to do it in Python. It may not be great Python code, but you'll learn more about how it suits you than from an essay. I know the first time I looked at Python, I didn't give it much chance (just looked like Matlab as far as I was concerned), but after using it for a couple of years, I have to say I have no regrets.

Answer (score 2):

Paul Prescod [Why I Promote Python](http://www.prescod.net/python/why.html) has many good points why python is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Why Python? [Because all the cool kids are doing it](http://qa.debian.org/popcon-graph.php?packages=python+ruby&show_vote=on&want_legend=on&want_ticks=on&from_date=2007-01-01&to_date=&hlght_date=&date_fmt=%25Y-%25m&beenhere=1).

Disclaimer: I just noticed "popularity-contest" running on my machine so I investigated. Although quite useful for QA and planning, one can't actually derive any meaning from that graph which could at least as well be explained by the rise of Ubuntu installations and their Python based administrative tools. This link is for amusement purposes only, void in Idaho and Nebraska.